# how to make a form disappear upon clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, addeventlistener

Alright so I'm making a website where you can make your own digital card so in the main HTML I have the introduction and then they click make card and a 320px by 480px box opens up with options in a form format on what color the background should be etc... Now after they do this and click the button at the bottom I want the form to not be visible and create the card in the same window but I can't get my code workin i used a for loop with it:

```
    <script>   
        document.forms[0]['submit'].addEventListener('click', createCard);

        var formTotal = document.forms[0];

        function createCard(){
            for(i = 0; i <= formTotal.length; i++){
                formTotal[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

In the initial page I had a script in the header as such:

```
 function giftCard(){ 
        window.open("cardForm.html","Gift Card","width=320, height=480");
    }
```

and then used onclick in my html to initialize it to open the window:

```
<-button onclick="giftCard()">Make Card<-/button>
```

worked perfect but I don't think that will help with me trying to hide the visibility of my form in my new window. some suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you need. You don't really explain how the new window code fits in with what you are asking. Instead of looping through the form and hiding each element, why not just hide the form itself? Or, put the entire form inside of a div and just hide the div?

Comment: on the sidenote, you should set your createCard() function block before the addEventListener, to avoid hint issues.

Comment: Does the new window have access to the JavaScript that you included in your question?

Comment: @Don Zacharias yes it is the javascript in the new window the only javascript needed in the original window is hi welcome click below to being you card. which then the giftCard() function is passed to that button and the new window opens with a form. and a button at the bottom saying create card I then need to hide the form and I'm going to using absolue positioning to create the card the card is simple it asks your name, background color, color of text (Happy Birthday "name"!) and then a checkbox with three different images you may include( a heart dove and a star).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onsubmit` to bind the event for the form.

```js
  
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(event){
  createCard(event);
}
 
function createCard(event){      
  event.target.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
<input/>
<input/>
<input/>
<input/>
<button type="submit">
 submit
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm only using Javascript I don't use JQuery but thank you for the answer I still have given you a one up for it being correct, @MrVaykadji your javascript code seems to work but why is the 'event' needed within the function() and createCard() as a parameter. Also when you take the snippet within the function createCard(){ event.target.etc...} what is the target referring to as the event elements. and after explaining this is their a way to turn this code into an addEventListener way to hide it, sorry I'm trying to learn all possible ways so I can be more knowledgeable in the field.

Comment: @MrVaykadji another thing is when I do it, it does not hide it like your example does it clears the page and in  the center displays:

No data received

Which I think is because of the method="POST".

Is there any other way to do this by hiding the form using visibility = "hidden", or even style.display ="none" (though I'd prefer the visibility = "hidden" version).

Comment: @NarinderSharma this solution is pure JavaScript. I have not used any Jquery in it.

Answer (score 2):

Give the form a class(in HTML) at begining of form

```
  <div class ="form-hide">
```

In JQuery

```
  $('#submit').click(function(){
     $('.form-hide').hide();
   });
```

Comment: This is jQuery, not javascript

Comment: I've changes the heading as Jquery from Javascript .Careless Mistake :-).I think now there is no issue.The code did work however.Twas my explanation that was having a mistake.

Comment: and I added pure JS to complete it. Dunno if it really answers the question, but at least that answer will be complete^^